# Replace numbers with Roman numerals

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

I need a way to replace all occurrences of numbers represented as digits within a string with their Roman numeral equivalents.

Examples:

- `My 3 Top Tips: Part 19` should output `My III Top Tips: Part XIX`
- `Se7en` should output `Se7en` (since the character `7` is not a 'word')

It seems the best package out there for the job is [roman](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/roman).  Unfortunately it won't accept strings containing both text and numbers.

My thoughts are:

1. `split()` the text
2. iterate each `word`
3. is `word` a number, if so replace it using `roman`
4. merge the list together again

This just seems messy and error prone, and not very pythonic.  What are the better ways to do this?  Is it possible with a regex or list comprehension, or a combination of both?

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure that's the way to go!  But, I don't know how to make `re` replace a match with a function output - using the match itself as an argument

Comment: Did you look at the [documentation on re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)? I guess not, because if you had, you would have read that "If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string."

Comment: @rici Thanks for the tip

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I disagree that this is a duplicate of the question you have linked to, this is a much more specific problem. That question specifically concerns the actual conversion process.

Comment: The linked question has an answer outlining and implementing an excellent strategy for converting Arabic numbers to Roman numerals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find numbers that are not parts of larger words, use a regex with [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
regex = re.compile(r"\b\d+\b")
```

will only match `3` and `19` in your example, but not `7`.

So, using `write_roman()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28777219/20670), you can do

```
def repl(match):
    return write_roman(int(match.group(0)))

print(regex.sub(repl, "My 3 Top Se7en Tips: Part 19"))
```

and will get

```
My III Top Se7en Tips: Part XIX
```

Comment: you should add the code for translating the number to Roman, otherwise you are not answering his question (although pretty much you addressed the important part)