# Error in getting roman letter symbols:KeyError: '1000'

Tags: python-3.x

When I input 1000 its showing me **KeyError: '1000'**.Whats the error in this code.How complex is this code??.I know it takes 0.9 sec for 999

```
 symbols={'1':'I','2':'II','3' :'III','4': 'IV','5':' V','6': 'VI','7': 'VII','8': 'VIII','9': 'IX', '10':'X',
         '40':'XL','50':'L','60':'LX','70':'LXX','80':'LXXX','90':'XC','100':'C','400':'CD','700':'DCC','800':'DCCC','900':'CM','500':'D','M':'1000'}

  def get_roman(input1):

    n=len(str(input1))
    result=[]
    while(n>=1):
        unit_place=10**(int(n)-1)
        div=int(input1/unit_place)
        rem=input1%unit_place
        result.append(div*unit_place)
        input1=rem
        n -=1
    print(result)
```

This loop will print roman symbols which are not in symbols dict

```
for x in result:
       if (str(x) not in symbols):
        m=len(str(x))
        tenth=10**(int(m)-1)
        result_len=int(x/tenth)
        roman=symbols[str(tenth)]
        if(str(x)<=str(50)):
            symbols[str(x)]=roman*result_len
            print(symbols[str(x)],end='')
        elif('49'<str(x)<'90'):
            symbols[str(x)]=symbols['50']+symbols[str(x)]
            print(symbols[str(x)])
        elif(str(400)<str(x)<str(499)):
            print(symbols['400'],symbols[str(result[1])],symbols[str(result[-1])],sep='',end='')
        elif(str(499)<str(x)<str(900)):
            print(symbols['500'],symbols[str(result[1])],symbols[str(result[-1])],sep='',end='')
        elif(str(900)<str(x)<str(1000)):
            print(symbols['1000'],symbols[str(result[1])],symbols[str(result[-1])],sep='',end='')

    else:
        print(symbols[str(x)],sep='-',end='')
end=time.time()
print("It took"+str(start-end)+"seconds")
```

Comment: It looks like you made a really silly typo; `'M':'1000'` should be `'1000' : 'M'`.

Comment: Thankss...It takes 0.02...seconds for computing 2242.How complex is this code???.I have seen others doing this roman letter in 10 lines.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28777781/4909087

Comment: I saw their algorithm and mine takes more lines..anyways thanks dude