# In which Python module is the input() function?

Tags: python

I'm making a module which is meant to convert an integer parameter into a roman numeral string and am trying to find out where the input() function is 'cause I'd like to be able to save the roman numeral product to a variable in a manner similar to the one in the input() function, that is:

```
>>> foo = romannum (32)
>>> print (foo)
"XXXII"
```

Comment: `input` is a builtin. I can't follow the logic of your question for why you need to know where the function is. Are you asking about the CPython source code?

Comment: It doesn't look like `input` is in any way useful for implementing your `romannum` function anyway.

Comment: You can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28777781/7505395) to get a working int to roman-string function - `input()`is not touched at all-your question is unclear.

Comment: What do you need `input()` for? As others pointed out, your question is a little unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in the `builtins` module.

```
>>> import builtins
>>> builtins.input is input
True
>>> help(input)
Help on built-in function input in module builtins:

input(prompt=None, /)
    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.

    The prompt string, if given, is printed to standard output without a
    trailing newline before reading input.

    If the user hits EOF (*nix: Ctrl-D, Windows: Ctrl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
    On *nix systems, readline is used if available.
```

In Python 2, it was called `__builtin__`. But note that Python 3's `input()` is like Python 2's `raw_input()`.

---

If you want to implement your own custom input function, you can read from `sys.stdin` just like a file.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` is built in. A module doesn't need to import it for it to work. In Python 2, you would call `raw_input()`. If you want compatibility of python 2, you need to add:

`from future.builtins.misc import input`

To make it run seamlessly with python 2, you will [a little more work.](http://python3porting.com/) I hope this can help you.

Comment: There's no `from __future__ import input`.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry, that was stupid. I edited it to what I hope is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Especially the following lines :

Raises an auditing event ***builtins.input*** with argument prompt before reading input
Raises an auditing event ***builtins.input/result*** with the result after successfully reading