# roman numeral converter using python

Tags: python

I would like to ask if I should still continue this idea/way of roman numeral converter or should I think of a diff code.

Here is my current idea:

```
d_roman = { "I":1, "V": 5, "X":10}

rntconvert = raw_input("Enter Roman Num: " )

x = len(rntconvert)
if rntcovert is in dictionary

    #print value of rntcovert

elif x==2

    #add the value of two roman numbers except if first roman number is lower than the next then it will be subtracted 
    #(ex. IX, first char has lower value than next char, so it's like,  10 - 1)
```

Is this doable? Thank you in advance.

edit: im using 2.7
explanation is: i separated the solving per amount of string returned

Comment: Are you using python 2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic program to convert integer to Roman numerals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777219/basic-program-to-convert-integer-to-roman-numerals)

Comment: Your code is too messy. Please format it properly.

Comment: i will try my best to make it understandable, i'm sorry. i am still reading modules but i hardly understand without a pure lecture from my professors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is kind of correct, but to be frank it's expressed poorly, and will only work with strings of at most two letters. In the future it might help to work on a better formulation before trying to implement an algorithm, but for the time being I can give you an example of how I did it:

```
def from_roman_to_arabic(n):
    numerals={'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000}   
    adjust_values={'IV':2,'IX':2,'XL':20,'XC':20,'CD':200,'CM':200}  
    s=0
    for i in n: 
        s+=numerals[i]
    for j in adjust_values:
        if j in n: 
            s-=adjust_values[j]
    return s
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this:

```py
class solution:
    def roman_to_int(self, s):
        rom_val = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}
        int_val = 0
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if i > 0 and rom_val[s[i]] > rom_val[s[i - 1]]:
                int_val += rom_val[s[i]] - 2 * rom_val[s[i - 1]]
            else:
                int_val += rom_val[s[i]]
        return int_val

print(solution().roman_to_int('MMMCMLXXXVI'))
print(solution().roman_to_int('MMMM'))
print(solution().roman_to_int('C'))
```

Answer (score 0):

my solution:

```
d={"I":1,"V":5,"X":10,"L":50,"C":100,"D":500,"M":1000}

str=input("Enter roman number : ").upper()
sum=0
i=0
while(i<len(str)):
    if(i+1<len(str)):
        if(d[str[i]]>=d[str[i+1]]):
            sum+=d[str[i]]
            i+=1
        else:
            sum+=(d[str[i+1]]-d[str[i]])
            i+=2
    else:
        sum+=d[str[i]]
        i+=1
print("Integer value =",sum)
```