# How to Add some text in row by row in particular column in csv using python

Tags: python, excel, csv

Please solve in Python:

I am having CSV file with first Column Like this: 
The same name stored every 3 rows in these columns.

I like to add: 
first row FIRST name with - I, 
second row FIRST name with -II, 
third row FIRST name with -III 
and there Fourth row SECOND name with -I ...

***Example***

```
[Column]
 
 NAME

 - ROW[1] A
 - ROW[2] A
 - ROW[3] A
 - ROW[4] B
 - ROW[5] B
 - ROW[6] B
 - ROW[7] C
 - ROW[8] C
 - ROW[9] C
```

I should Add -I,-II,-III as below like this:

```
NAME
 - ROW[1]  A-I
 - ROW[2] A-II
 - ROW[3] A-III
 - ROW[4] B-I
 - ROW[5] B-II
 - ROW[6] B-III
 - ROW[7] C-I
 - ROW[8] C-II
 - ROW[9] C-III
```

I have Tried this Below Code:

```
    
    import pandas as pd
    f, deldict = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\muthu\\Desktop\\Test.csv"), {} 
    f['NAME'] = f['NAME'] +'-I' 
    f = f[['NAME', 'AGE', 'ADDRESS']]   
    print (f)
    f.to_csv('Newtest.csv',index=False)
```

This Above Code Changed Total Name Column Row Data with "-I"
But how to add row by row (-I,-II,-III,-I,-II,-III) for my above requirement ?.

Comment: Hi, `muthu`, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? We could help you if you showed us some code that you wrote yourself.

Comment: In pseudo-code do the following:
 1) Read the file line-by-line
 2) At the end of each line append the desired postfix using a `loop`
 3) Write the data to the file

Answer (score 0):

We:

1. Read the file
2. Use dictionary to track names counts
3. Update name with a prefix of it's counter as roman number
4. Save file again

***Pandas Solution***

```
import pandas as pd

from collections import OrderedDict

# From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777219/basic-program-to-convert-integer-to-roman-numerals
def number_to_roman(num):
    roman = OrderedDict()
    roman[1000] = "M"
    roman[900] = "CM"
    roman[500] = "D"
    roman[400] = "CD"
    roman[100] = "C"
    roman[90] = "XC"
    roman[50] = "L"
    roman[40] = "XL"
    roman[10] = "X"
    roman[9] = "IX"
    roman[5] = "V"
    roman[4] = "IV"
    roman[1] = "I"
    def roman_num(num):
        for r in roman.keys():
            x, y = divmod(num, r)
            yield roman[r] * x
            num -= (r * x)
            if num <= 0:
                break
    return "".join([a for a in roman_num(num)])

filename="sabich.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

def roman_count_rename_column(df, column_name='Name', start_row=0, seperator='-'):
    names_count = dict()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if index < start_row:
            continue
        name = row[column_name]
        names_count[name] = names_count.get(name, 0) + 1
        df.at[index, column_name] = name + seperator + number_to_roman(names_count[name])
    return df

df = roman_count_rename_column(df)
df.to_csv(filename)
```

***Excel Solution***

```
import openpyxl

filename="sabich.xlsx"

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)

from collections import OrderedDict

# From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777219/basic-program-to-convert-integer-to-roman-numerals
def number_to_roman(num):
    roman = OrderedDict()
    roman[1000] = "M"
    roman[900] = "CM"
    roman[500] = "D"
    roman[400] = "CD"
    roman[100] = "C"
    roman[90] = "XC"
    roman[50] = "L"
    roman[40] = "XL"
    roman[10] = "X"
    roman[9] = "IX"
    roman[5] = "V"
    roman[4] = "IV"
    roman[1] = "I"
    def roman_num(num):
        for r in roman.keys():
            x, y = divmod(num, r)
            yield roman[r] * x
            num -= (r * x)
            if num <= 0:
                break
    return "".join([a for a in roman_num(num)])

def roman_count_rename_column(sheet, column_position='A', start_row=2, seperator='-'):
    row_number = start_row
    current_cell = sheet[f"{column_position}{row_number}"]
    names_count = dict()
    while current_cell.value:
        print(f'In {column_position}{row_number} value {current_cell.value}')
        # Update name counter
        names_count[current_cell.value] = names_count.get(current_cell.value, 0) + 1
        sheet[f"{column_position}{row_number}"].value = current_cell.value + seperator + number_to_roman(names_count[current_cell.value])
        row_number += 1
        current_cell = sheet[f"{column_position}{row_number}"]

sheet = workbook.active
roman_count_rename_column(sheet, column_position='A')

workbook.save(filename)
```

Input: 
[image]

Output: 
[image]

Comment: This is what would happen if names are at a sequence like [A, A, A, B, B, B, C, C, C] :)
The solution attached is even more generalized and would remain correct even in the case where names order is switched @muthu

Comment: @muthu added another solution in Pandas

Comment: Its worked Sucessfully. Thankyou very much for your help @ Aviv Yaniv.