# Integer to Roman

Tags: python

The question requires me to return the roman numerals for an integer.

- 3 - III
- 4 - IV
- 27 - XXVII
- 319 - CCCXIX

This is my code -

```
class Solution(object):
    def intToRoman(self, num):
        """
        :type num: int
        :rtype: str
        """
        dict = {
            "I" : 1,
            "IV": 4,
            "V" : 5,
            "IX" : 9,
            "X" : 10, 
            "XL" : 40,
            "L" : 50,
            "XC" : 90,
            "C" : 100, 
            "CD" : 400,
            "D" : 500, 
            "CM" : 900,
            "M" : 1000
        }
        
        returnee = ""
        for k, v in reversed(dict.items()):
            while num > 0: 
                if v <= num:
                    returnee += k
                    num -= v
                else:
                    break
        return returnee
```

This does not work as the integer nine returns IVIVI instead of IX. Could someone please explain where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your code returns "IX" for me. Your code depends on the dict being ordered — are you using a recent enough version of Python to count on that? (also don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's a built-in in python) Since you are just looping over items, there's no reason to use a dict here. You could just make a list of tuples.

Comment: the `reversed(dict.items())` should be `reversed(list(dict.items()))`

Comment: Compare your code to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28777781/9192284) on another question.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori What difference does that make?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy I'm using Python 3.7.7, when I ran OP's code, it raised a `'dict_items' object is not reversible` error here.

Comment: @leaf_yakitori They're getting a result (IVIVI), so that's not an issue for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where I am going wrong?

Using Python 2. Pick Python 3.

(You rely on the order of the dict items, and Python 3 has officially had dicts ordered since 3.7, which is over three years old.)

Comment: Note to downvoter-wannabes: The class/function/docstring make me suspect it's [at LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/integer-to-roman/). Plus Python 2 is called "Python" there and this wouldn't be the first time people use Python 2 without wanting to. Plus I tested it and got `"IVIVI"` with that there as well.

Comment: Better be specific about the Python version of >= 3.6. You should also mention what makes the code work in Python 3.6+ for this answer to be a valid answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @blhsing I neither "ask for more information" nor "suggest improvements". I'm answering their question and we shall "Avoid answering questions in comments". It often seems nobody is reading the comment box's instructions. But ok, I'll add something.